# Convert List<double> into object[]

Tags: c#

I have some dynamic list collection and this is added on run time. I want to convert those ListColl in to array of object. The below is my code

```
 List<double> ListColl = new List<double>();
 // This is added dynamically and finally want to convert this list into object array
  values.Add(10);
  values.Add(40);
  values.Add(20);
```

Expected output is like this

```
object[] objArray = new object[] { 10, 40, 20 };
```

I used `object[] objArray = ListColl.ToArray()`. But this is throwing error.

How to convert this list collection in to array of object

Comment: "But this is throwing error." - always, always specify what the error is.

Comment: Please only use the asp.net tag when the question is genuinely related to asp.net - there's *nothing* asp.net-specific here.

Comment: The error will be because ListColl.ToArray() will produce an array of type double, not an array of type object. (object[] != double[])

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [`Cast<object>()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341406%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) call followed by `ToArray()`:

```
object[] objArray = ListColl.Cast<object>().ToArray();
```

Answer (score 2):

Method Syntax:

```
object[] objArray = ListColl.Cast<object>().ToArray();
```

Query Syntax:

```
var objArray = (from item in ListColl select item as object).ToArray();
```

Comment: Technically both those are using Linq, but the first uses `Method` syntax, while the second uses `Query` syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Since LINQ uses IEnumerable under the hood, it is possible that the result provided in some of the other answers is provided by resizing the destination array one or multiple times, as the ToArray() method might not know in advance how many elements are in the list. If such performance considerations are important, perhaps you want to write your own extension method like so:

```
public static object[] ToObjArray<T>(this List<T> source)
{
    var objArray = new object[source.Count];
    for (int i = 0; i < source.Count; i++)
        objArray[i] = source[i];
    return objArray;
}
```

This will allocate an array of the exact size needed, and use constant-time access to items, making for an execution time linear in the list length.